# How to evaluate these 2 hash functions?

Tags: c#, hash

Code 1: (a simple way to convert SHA1 result to a string)

```
byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
SHA1CryptoServicesProvider x = new SHA1CryptoServicesProvider();
bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in bs)
   s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
result1 = s.ToString();
```

Code2: (a legacy code that existed in projects from the beginning of the world)

```
byte[] bs = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(input);
SHA1CryptoServicesProvider x = new SHA1CryptoServicesProvider();
bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
char[] c = new char[bs.length]
for(int i=0; i<bs.length; i++)
  c[i] = (char)(bs[i] & 0x7f);
resutl2 = new StringBuilder().Append(c).ToString();
```

Is there any `map()` function to evaluate `result1` with `result2`?

```
result1 == map(result2)
```

And what does the "Code 2" mean by `0x7f`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "evaluate result1 with result2"?

Comment: 0x7f is a hexdecimal number 7f. f is 15 and 7 is 7, so it would be 0111 1111 in binary, or 127 in decimal

Comment: `0x7f` in ascii mean **(del)**

Comment: ...by other words it removes sign bit from number

Comment: @legendinmaking It does mean 0x7f in ASCII, but that is meaningless in this context (not being interpreted as ASCII) :)

Comment: @Pratush yeah, my ignorance  Marc Gravell♦ has explained it quite well

Comment: @MartinV. well, it is being applied to a `byte`; `byte` is *unsigned* - it *doesn't have a sign bit* (`sbyte` does). You could perhaps say it removes the MSB.

Answer (score 2):

> And what does the "Code 2" mean by 0x7f?

The `& 0x7f` means `& 128`, i.e. "only keep the first (least significant) 7 bits", which forces the output to remain pure ASCII (ASCII only uses 7-bits) - by simply throwing away any information that doesn't fit.

> Is there any `map()` function to evaluate `result1` with `result2`?

The biggest problem, though, is using a different encoding at the start: unless `input` only ever includes ASCII text (i.e. characters where only the first 7 bits are used), you are hashing completely different byte-arrays (`bs`), so the final output will not be equatable in any way. Since the hash is not trivially reversible you will not be able to compensate for this.

Answer (score 2):

Your second code is bad in four ways:

- It assumes the input string is entirely composed of ASCII characters. (Your first code copes with all of Unicode)
- It loses the top bit of each byte in the result, by using `b & 0x7f` - that's just a bitwise "AND" with the binary value 01111111, so the result is in the range 0-127 instead of 0-255
- It ends up with non-printable text in many cases which may very well end up being corrupted in some transformations
- (Far less important) It's using a StringBuilder for no reason; the final line could just be

  ```
  result2 = new string(c);
  ```

Given a `result1` value, you *can* work out whether the original text would map to a given `result2` value (assuming the original text was ASCII in the first place), but you can't work the other way round, because data has been lost. (There are several `result2` values which could produce the same `result1` value.) That's even assuming that you can obtain the exact `result2` value at all - due to the way it ends up using control characters, you may well find even more data is being lost.

Answer (score 0):

In code 1, we see:

`s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());`

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx we see that byte's toString("x2") means that each byte will be rendered as two hexidecimal digits, and then lowercased - so 0a, f9, etc.

But in code 2 we see:

`c[i] = (char)(bs[i] & 0x7f);`

Doing (bs[i] & 0x7f); means we remove the eighth bit (set it to 0) before placing it in the returned value. Meaning that we have LOST information in the original hash - approximately one eighth of it is wiped out. Meaning we cannot determine what result1 would be using any function on result2 - but you could go the other way, do a function on result1 that gives you result 2, by turning it back into a byte array.

If the intention of code 2 is to render the hash a printable string, base64 encoding is a better idea (google it) (of course, printable hexadecimal encoding is fine too)

Also, both code 1 and code 2 use different encodings at the start. If the string passed to code 1/2 has unicode in it, not just pure ASCII, you will immediately have different things getting hashed, which is irreconcilable immediately.

Comment: meh; base-64 shaves 12 characters (28 in base-64, 40 in hex), but it is very difficult to say base64 is "better" than hex. They both convey the data in a perfectly round-trippable way.

Comment: I didn't say base64 is better than hex - I said it's better than throwing out 1/8th of the hash's information! :)